# mysql Query - no more entries for same qID and same userID

Tags: php, mysql

The following description is a simple example with questions and answers. But the logic of my site is similar.

Lets say tables are:

```
USERS table: USER_ID, etc
QUESTIONS table: QUESTION_ID, TEXT, CATEGORY, CORRECT_RESPONSE, AVAILABLE
RESPONSES table: QUESTION_ID, USER_ID, RESPONSE_VALUE
PROFILE table: USER_ID, CATEGORY_Questions, YEAR, NUMBER_OF_ANSWERED, Number_OF_CORRECT, POINTS
```

The questions will be available to be answered by users for few hours. Every question has the same 3 choices for answers YES/NO/DEPENDS.

So I want users to go click on one of them for example and store an entry on RESPONSES table (ok this query is easy) and then not be able to answer the same question again.
Users will be able to edit the question for some time and after this period I want the question to be shown as answered, until the end of the day that I will mark the question as AVAILABLE=NO and it will removed from the unanswered questions... What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are alot of ways to achieve this depending on the context one of these is create a boolean `bit` column called answered and another column `AnswerDate datetime or timestamp` then when the user answer a question add the answer time then using php or javascript in handling the update of the flag `answered` in the table after a period of time that you want has elapsed.